# Indicative and subjunctive after time constructions

Tags: verbos, tiempo

I have a few questions regarding the use of some verbs after time constructions like "tan pronto como" or "en cuanto."

If I am saying....

> Los domingos por la mañana vemos televisión. Tan pronto como
>   ***_*_** , prendemos el televisor para ver nuestro programa favorito.

And I need to fill the blank with *levantarse*... would it be *nos levantamos*? I am confused because the action happens every sunday but is not past tense.

Another:

> Algunos me dicen terco, pero yo siempre sigo luchando hasta que
>   ***_*_** mis metas.

If I need to fill it with *lograr* do I place *logro* meaning "until I achieve" or the subjunctive? This also happens multiple times but it seems like the subjunctive could fit.

Last one:

> Todos los veranos, Martin Y Felícita visitan a sus abuelos en México. Cuando ellos ***_*_** en la casa de sus abuelos.

I have to fill it with *llegar*. It seems like the present is the way to go (*llegan*) but it (again) happens multiple times.

Which form do I fill the blanks with?

Answer (score 4):

Although there may be several options, you can just make the person and tense concordant with those of the previous verb, thus:

> Los domingos por la mañana **vemos** televisión.

This is indicative present, first person plural. So we use indicative present, first person plural for *levantarse*:

> en cuanto **nos levantamos**...

Another:

> yo siempre **sigo luchando**...

This is present, first person singular, so

> hasta que **consigo**

Whis is also present, first person singular.

Another:

> Martin Y Felícita **visitan**...

present, third person plural

> Cuando **llegan** a...

Again present, third person plural

See? it's easy!

Answer (score 2):

> Tan pronto como **nos levantamos**, prendemos el televisor

It's present tense, actually. And it's the same as in English ("as soon as we get up, we turn on..."), I think

> Algunos me dicen terco, pero yo siempre sigo luchando hasta que **logro** mis metas

It's, again, present, your are not referring to an uncertain future event, but to a "present" certain event. Actually a series of events, but that series as a whole is in the present: it's not in the past nor in the future.

It would be different if you'd say:

> yo seguiré  luchando hasta que **logre** mi meta

Here the event is in the future, and is uncertain: subjunctive.

> Todos los veranos, Martin Y Felícita visitan a sus abuelos en México. Cuando ellos **llegan** a la casa de sus abuelos.......

(it's "llegan a", not "llegan en"). The same as the previous ones: present. It refers to a repeated series of events that occurs, as a whole, in the present.

Answer (score 0):

Tan pronto como NOS LEVANTAMOS, prendemos ... 'nosotros nos levantamos' may refer either the past or present, this case is the present.

2 use the subjunctive, 'hasta que logre' mis metas.

3 use llegan, it refers to the present

Comment: In the second one, subjunctive is not right. Presente de indicativo, as DeStrangis said.